# Is the Current of A Full Wave Bridge Rectifier Roughly Constant?

Tags: current, ac, dc, bridge-rectifier

If I have a full wave bridge rectifier that produces pulsed DC output (without any type of filtering) is the current constant from the AC side to the DC side? In other words: if the input is .5A AC input will the output be .5A DC output?

Comment: Not entirely, because you don't get pure DC from just a rectifier.

Comment: The *rms* current may be the same (for a 1:1 transformer). Peak currents in rectifiers is the source of many a circuit fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a diode bridge with no smoothing capacitor, the instantaneous current on the AC side **MUST** equal the magnitude of the instantaneous current on the DC side.

> if the input is .5A AC input will the output be .5A DC output?

No that isn't quite true - the RMS currents will be equal i.e. produce the same power when feeding a resistor of the same value. The "DC output" could be taken as meaning the average output from the rectifier and this won't equal the RMS of the input current to the bridge.